# Golang Dep: having multiple binaries in one source tree

Tags: go, dependencies

Having the following Go project layout with shared library functions in `lib` and several binaries in `cmd` using these library functions and having external dependencies:

```
root
   |
   lib
   cmd
     |
     binary1
           |
           main.go
     binary2
           |
           main.go
     ...
```

Searching for a simple way to handle project dependencies with `dep` tool. What is the expected usage pattern: having multiple `Gopkg.*` files in each `binaryX` directory or using a pair of `Gopkg.toml` and `Gopkg.lock` files for all these binaries? In the second case how would we compile these binaries knowing that `vendor` directory will be in project root instead of `binaryX` directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'd just have a single root/vendor directory that all your various deps that are referenced by the `lib` and `cmd` code

When compiling, just do it like normal.

`go install ./cmd/...`

(or however you want to build)